# 19.10: Add Ubuntu alongside existing Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

500gb hard disk. Legacy bios mode. I want to install both windows 10 and ubuntu 19.10. How should i create partitions for both (details like primary or logical, ext4 or 3 or ntfs, size of each partition(for ubuntu i want root, swap and home), which one to install first) and anything you want to add.
Laptop came with already partitioned hard disk in ntfs format and windows installed.

Comment: Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Comment: A swap partition is passe unless you expect to use Hibernation in Linux; see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq and just let the installer create a swap file automagically if no Hibernation needed. Ubuntu's preferred partition type is ext4 and will be installed automatically. Once you make a LiveUSB, install by these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.  Step 6 Allocate Disk Space https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space will show 'Something Else' or "Install alongside Windows'; latter is preferred.

Comment: 'Install alongside Windows' automates reducing the Windows NTFS partition and making the root partition. wht do you want a separate /home partition instead of letting the installer put /home under root?

Comment: The separate /swap and /home partitions is a preference, and seems like you may not be experienced enough yet to have experienced the consequences of that choice. I recommend using the installer defaults, which are different, but quite safe and sane.

Comment: If i use 'install alongside windows' option, will it shrink the c drive and install ubuntu in the newly formed partition? If i have a free space in hard disk and still choose the same option, will it install the ubuntu in that free space?